# Setting up permissions

Tags: hooks, users

My cars data is as the following:

```
id    make        no         parent
1     bmw         NULL          0
2     bmw         bmw987        1
3     bmw         bmw654        1
4     ferrari     NULL          0
5     ferrari     ferrari987    4
6     ferrari     ferrari654    4
```

(Note: I am using two tables for above data. This is just to get an idea of data.)

I am creating permissions to book cars as:

1. `Book bmw`; the user will have permission to book bmw987 and bmw654 means
   children of BMW
2. `book bmw987`; the user will have permission to book bmw9987 only.
3. `Book ferrari`; the user will have permission to book all Ferrari cars.

In my car booking portal, I have 100's of cars and many makes. When I used hook_permission() and loop through all available cars to create book permission on each car, it pollutes my permission page (admin/people/permission) and believe me handling these many permission will faint Admin.

Is there any other alternative to handle such huge permission?

Comment: What about using this custom module: http://drupal.org/project/term_permissions ? Because I am using taxonomy vocabulary as car make and terms and car no's

Comment: _Custom module_ is not a term used to mean any module hosted on Drupal.org; it means a module that is too specific to be used on other sites, if not for the site for which is thought; the [Drupal.org customizations](http://drupal.org/project/drupalorg) module is an example of custom module.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try something like this

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['example/car/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Example RSS feed', 
    'page callback' => 'example_feed', 
    'access arguments' => 'mymodule_abc_view', 
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );
    return $items;
}

function mymodule_abc_view() {
    return 'TRUE after checking something';
}
```

your URL should pass the car id or something to check the permission.

Comment: This will be done after I have permissions saved somewhere. My problem is that I have a huge set of permissions and I cannot manage them.

Comment: No you can write appropriate TRUE condition after making cases etc in mymodule_abc_view function like 
switch ($user->uid)
  {
    case 1 :
    case 7 : return TRUE;
             break;
    case 2 :
    case 3 :
    case 4 :
    case 5 :
    case 6 : return FALSE;
             break;
   }
etc

Comment: what is the use of function mymodule_abc_view?

Comment: Plese check answer now. 'access arguments' => 'mymodule_abc_view',

Comment: also you should choose best answer if any.